# Spring Neo4j : passing list as parameter

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I've tried to pass list as parameter but unfortunately the result return nothing. It should return all posts based on the supplied postId in list format.

**Query :**

```java
@Query("MATCH (n:Post)-[r]-(u) WHERE n.postId IN {postId} RETURN n,r,u")
List<Post> getPost(@Param("postId") List postIdList);
```

Do spring-data-neo accept list parameter and IN clause? I've tried to search around the web but didn't find any guides.

**Updates :**

**Query :**

```java
@Query("MATCH (n:Post)-[r]-(u) WHERE n.postId IN {postId} RETURN n,r,u")
List<Post> getPost(@Param("postId") List<String> postIdList);
```

**Sdn & ogm :**

[image]

Comment: Which driver do you use?

Comment: Probably not related (though SDN might use the information to try and find a converter), but you should use a `List` with a type parameter instead of the raw type.

Comment: Yes, it does. The only difference I can see to my queries is  - as already put by Frank - that I pass a typed list.

Comment: This should work regardless of parameterized types. As Luanne mentioned could you please let us know what driver you are using (HTTP, Bolt, Embedded). Also that your query is returning data through the browser for a specific data set; and what versions of SDN/OGM you are using.

Comment: @Luanne : org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver

Comment: @FrankPavageau: I've updated the script : added <String>

Comment: Should work. Which version of Sdn and ogm

Comment: @Luanne : I've updated the info as above

Comment: Okay, I've tested this works on 4.2. Will try 4.1 and let you know

Comment: Works with 4.1.4 as well. Would suggest you upgrade- 4.1.1 is really old