# How to Query Spring Data Neo4j with List Argument

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, swagger, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to execute the query "find all merchants whose ids are in this list" (where the id is `@GeneratedValue` UUID string) in my spring data neo4j application.

Using [query methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation), that would (AFAIK) translate to either of:

```
List<Merchant> findByIdIn(List<String> ids);
List<Merchant> findByIdIsIn(List<String> ids);
```

In my swagger UI, I can see the endpoints, but when I pass in a valid id, no results are returned:
[image]
[image]

However, if I execute the same method programatically, the correct results are returned:
[image]

Similarly, the `GET /merchants/90c55d4b-b3dc-4ae3-ab43-4d6ff523a20b` endpoint returns the expected element.[image]

This leads me to believe the internal translation of the HTTP request to the query isn't correct (most likely due to the list arg). The exact same thing happens (no results are returned) if I use a custom `@Query`, despite using the accepted solution from this [s/o question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40129604/4803964):

```
@Query("MATCH (m: Merchant)" +
    "WHERE m.id in $merchantId " +
    "RETURN m")
List<Merchant> customQuery(List<String> merchantIds);
```

Am I missing something here? How do I query using a list as an argument? Thanks!

Comment: When you trigger the query via swagger, is the list coming correctly? I believe that's the issue since programmatically it's working fine. If it's not coming, then neither this nor custom query will work

Comment: The API spec seems to be generated incorrectly - the `ids` parameter in Swagger UI appears as an array of _objects_ rather than an array of _strings_. Check the documentation of your framework/library to see if query parameters need special annotations in order to generate the correct API spec.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor I believe so. The swagger ui shows the following request being generated `curl -X 'GET'  'http://localhost:8080/merchants/search/findByIdIn?ids=%2290c55d4b-b3dc-4ae3-ab43-4d6ff523a20b%22'`, which when decoded is `curl -X 'GET'  'http://localhost:8080/merchants/search/findByIdIn?ids="90c55d4b-b3dc-4ae3-ab43-4d6ff523a20b"'`

Comment: @Helen I believe the type is automatically extracted from the variable and so I do not have control

Comment: Edit: I was able to get it to work using postman. It seems the quotes I used to wrap the string in the swagger UI are breaking the request. If I omit the quotes from swagger, it complains that the type is wrong, suggesting that @Helen you are on the right track. I guess I need to figure out how to tell swagger to change the type. If anyone knows how to do that, please let me know!

Comment: Please give us some code about the controller, and the request body class.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor there is no controller, the endpoint is auto-generated by spring data. There is no request body, the args are query parameters and are fully summarised by `List<String>`

Comment: ok, then can you share github repo where we can replicate it?